# Checking for 2 different strings in the same list

Tags: python, string, list, compare

What I mean by that is, that I want to take a list, let's say"

```
["i","am","you","pure","fact"],
```

then check whether this `list` contains 2 different strings, like `"i"` and `"pure"`, and then if true, it runs something.
This is what I am looking for, but in PYTHON.
I don't know how to do this sort of check.

Comment: Okay. Where are you stuck? Do you know how to check whether _one_ string is in a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out

```py
elements: list = ["i","am","you","pure","fact"]
str1: str = "i"
str2: str = "pure"

if str1 in elements and str2 in elements:
    # Execute code
    ...
```